# Expectional number and identity

Tags: probability, expectation

We draw $k$ balls from urn where balls are numbered from $1$ to $n$ (with returning).
Let $X$-the smallest drawn ball, $Y$- the biggest one.
Show that $\mathbb{E}X+\mathbb{E}Y=n+1$.

I've tried to set the distribution of that random variables. But then it was very hard to calculate the expectation number. What's more I've noticed that $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}Y$. 
I failed...

Do you have any idea how to show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Z:=X+Y$ then $Z$ and $2n+2-Z$ have equal distribution.

Consequently $$\mathbb{E}Z=2n+2-\mathbb{E}Z$$
hence $$\mathbb EZ=n+1$$

---

edit to make things more clear:

Let it be so that for $k=1,\dots,n$ ball with original number $k$ is also equipped with a second number $n+1-k$.

If we are looking at these second numbers then the largest drawn is $n+1-X$ and the smallest drawn is $n+1-Y$. We are dealing with a similar experiment so $(n+1-X)+(n+1-Y)$ will have the same distribution as $X+Y$.

Comment: I cant see why $Z$ has the same distribution as $2n+2-Z$

Comment: For $k=1,\dots,n$ give ball $k$ a second number $n+1-k$. Then the largest second number drawn will be $n+1-X$ and the smallest second number drawn will be $n+1-Y$. Their sum is $2n+2-Z$.